# Solving for perfect Bayesian equilibria of the following game

Tags: game-theory, bayesian

I've come up with a rather complex game, illustrated below, and need some help to get started on solving for the (weak) perfect Bayesian equilibria.

[image]

I've written the beliefs of player 1 as variables next to nodes. $P_1$ chooses $A$ or $B$ then $P_2$ must simultaneously pick $a$ or $b$ ($P_2$ acts simultaneously if $P_1$ chooses $A$ or $B$, similarly for $A'$ or $B'$).

A first step I have seen in the literature for computing PBE is to write out all the choices of both players and nature, then enumerate through all the separating, pooling, and semi-separating cases.

- $P_1$ has three information sets

  - Info set 1: $P_1$ can choose between $A$, $B$, and $C$
  - Info set 2: $P_1$ can choose between $A'$ and $B'$
  - Info set 3: $P_1$ can choose between $A'$ and $B'$
- $P_2$ has four information sets

  - Info set 1: $P_2$ can choose between $a$ and $b$
  - Info set 2: $P_2$ can choose between $a$ and $b$
  - Info set 3: $P_2$ can choose between $a'$ and $b'$
  - Info set 4: $P_2$ can choose between $a'$ and $b'$
- Nature makes two choices:

  - the original state of nature
  - the outcome of player 1's move $C$

Are the above cases correct? Do I need to check separating, pooling, semi-pooling for each combination? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**Note:** There are two moves by Nature (N). $P_1$ doesn't see the outcome of nature's first move, $P_2$ doesn't see the outcome of nature's second move. As far as I understand, one can translate this game into one where nature settles all of the randomness at the root node, but I think this makes the tree (possibly much) bigger. I'm hoping it can be analyzed in its current form.

**Issue:** The third and fourth information states for player 2 don't seem to be correct as written. Player $2$ should have a belief over the outcome of nature's second move, but I'm not sure how to denote that.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For a complex game like this, I don't see any shortcut but solution by brute force. That is, for each strategy of P1, determine P2's beliefs at his four information sets, then calculate P2's best response, and lastly determine whether P1's strategy is a best response to P2's best response (to it) based on P1's belief. I tried briefly to find a weak PBE in pure strategies but there doesn't seem to be any. You may have to look for a mixed strategy weak PBE instead.

Comment: Thanks @HerrK.! Yeah, that was my fear. Okay, I will run through it. By mixed strategy, do you mean semi-separating equilibrium? It appears that the terminology "pooling" and "separating" is used to be synonymous with pure strategies?

Comment: The pooling/separating/semi-separating division is in reference to signaling games, and more particularly to the amount of information transmitted in the equilibria of such games. Pooling and separating equilibria correspond to zero and full information transmission, respectively. Semi-separating equilibrium is the intermediate case, where the informed player mixes at one information set and uses a pure strategy at another. The game you have is more complex than the canonical signaling game, so I wouldn't stick too tight to the classification of equilibria used therein.

Comment: (Cont'd) That being said, you should be able to find a mixed strategy weak PBE by letting P1 randomize between $A$ and $B$ at the top info set and P2 randomize between $a$ and $b$ at the top two info set; the other info sets will thus be reached with zero probability and so it's easy to construct beliefs and sequentially rational responses there. There will likely be other mixed weak PBE as well, but they will take some work to find out.

Comment: Thank you @HerrK. I've been working through the equilibria following your suggestions.